AWS Monitoring/Provisioning Custom internal app or off the shelf?
Bottom Line Up Front
We’re looking for a solution to streamline deployment, provisioning, and monitoring across different environments. Currently, deployment happens through Azure DevOps, provisioning via AWS CloudFormation, and monitoring using CloudWatch graphs. We’re considering creating a custom application for deployment and provisioning, while using Grafana for monitoring.
With Our logical separation/grouping of services we don't feel that using the existing AWS tools are a good option for making an 'easy-button'.
What other options have you found successful?
What tools have you found to be limiting and difficult to use?
Have you created a successful options creating a single pane of glass for monitoring that would also allow us to provision within the same app/view?
Additional Background:
We have several applications developed by separate teams, which we refer to as self-contained systems. Each of these systems has its own CloudFormation templates that create AWS resources. Think of these as microservices owned by individual teams. We use different runtime environments (including logical environments beyond AWS regions). Our deployment and version control process currently relies on Azure DevOps. Initially, we started with a few microservices and few teams, but now we have grown and have more teams and many more services and environments. This makes it challenging to maintain an overview, not only for the ownership team but also for the infrastructure team.
Thanks all.
